# Почему блокируется поток в pyGTK после выполнения метода gtk.main()?

Tags: python, pygtk

У меня есть приложение, работающее в трее с использованием PyGTK. Приложение в работает в бесконечном цикле, сканируя файловую систему. Я планирую запустить в отдельном потоке модуль, который устанавливает иконку в трее, в основном же потоке будет работать сам цикл. Но здесь беда - метод gtk.main() блокирует выполнение моего скрипта. То есть поток как бы создается, но дальнейшая работа кода не выполняется. Вот пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# [SNIPPET_NAME: Systray icon]
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: PyGTK]
# [SNIPPET_DESCRIPTION: Shows a system tray icon with a menu  ]
# [SNIPPET_AUTHOR: João Pinto <joao.pinto@getdeb.net>]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: GPL]
#
# Модификация: Иванов Юрий aka HeaTTheatR
# Март, 2015
# Луганск
#
# Email: gleb.assert@mail.ru
# gorodage@gmail.com
#

import os
import types

from collections import OrderedDict

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
    import gtk
except ImportError, exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Install the library 'gtk' and 'pyGTK'\n{0}".format(str(exc))
    )

class SysTrayIconApp:
    """Устанавливает иконку  с пунктами меню в системный трей"""

    def __init__(self, label, icon, menu, quit):
        """
        type label: str
        param label: подпись трея

        type icon: str
        param icon: путь к иконке

        type menu: list
        param menu:[("Подпись кнопки", пользовательская функция))]

        type quit: bool
        param quit: если True - будет создан пункт "Quit" с функцией выхода

        """

        self.tray = gtk.StatusIcon()

        if icon is not None and os.path.exists(icon) and os.path.isfile(icon):
            pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(icon)
            scaled_buf = pixbuf.scale_simple(24, 24, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
            self.tray.set_from_pixbuf(scaled_buf)
        else:
            self.tray.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)

        self.tray.connect('popup-menu', self.on_right_click)
        self.tray.set_tooltip(label)

        if not menu:
            menu = [("Quit", gtk.main_quit)]
        if quit:
            menu.append(("Quit", gtk.main_quit))
        self.item_menu = menu

    def on_right_click(self, icon, event_button, event_time):
        self.make_menu(event_button, event_time)

    def make_menu(self, event_button, event_time):
        menu = gtk.Menu()

        # создаем коллекцию не отсортированных элементов
        collection = OrderedDict(self.item_menu)
        items = collection.keys()  # [имена пунктов]
        functions = collection.values()  # [функции, соответствующие пунктам]

        for i, name_item in enumerate(items):
            function = functions[i]
            if isinstance(function, types.MethodType) \
                    or isinstance(function, types.FunctionType) \
                    or isinstance(function, types.BuiltinFunctionType):
                    item = gtk.MenuItem(name_item)
                    item.show()
                    menu.append(item)
                    item.connect('activate', function)

        menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu,
                   event_button, event_time, self.tray)

def show(label="", icon=None, menu=None, quit=True):
    SysTrayIconApp(label, icon, menu, quit)
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import threading

    def show_about_dialog(widget=None):
        print "call <show_about_dialog>"

    def show_license(widget=None):
        print "call <show_license>"

    label = "This is the name of your program's"
    menu = [("About", show_about_dialog), ("License", show_license)]
    icon = "./icon.png"

    tray = threading.Thread(target=show, args=(label, icon, menu,))
    tray.run()

    # Здесь будет работать цикл while,
    # который будет сканировать файловую систему пользователя.
    print "There is a cycle to work 'while'"
```

Comment: Вы были правы в прошлый раз gtk.main() запускает mainloop - основной цикл обработки сообщений в программе. Представьте, что внутри gtk.main() есть свой цикл while, который прерывается вызовом gtk.main_quit().
Вам нужно создать отдельную функцию, в которой будет сканироваться файловая система, и зарегистрировать ее таким образом, чтобы она выполнялась по таймеру, например, каждые 100 мс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо того чтобы выполнять что-то после вызова gtk.mainloop(), присоедините функцию, которая будет выполнятся, например, по таймеру. Примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309006/running-function-5-seconds-after-pygtk-widget-is-shown):

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import glib

def timer_cb():
    print "5 seconds elapsed."
    return False

def show_cb(widget, data=None):
    glib.timeout_add(5000, timer_cb)

def destroy_cb(widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.connect("show", show_cb)

    window.connect("destroy", destroy_cb)

    window.show()

    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне кажется, правильное это решение!

Comment: Проверьте, если что пишите.

Comment: В принципе, это работает, но функция timer_cb вызывается не каждый, а ЧЕРЕЗ определенный промежуток времени. В общем, разницы нет, уже в ней я организовал рабочий цикл приложения. Кстати, а каким образом узнать имена событий, так как в gtk.StatusIcon нет события с именем "show"?

Comment: Ну если бы вызывалось каждый, то программа могла бы повиснуть, так что это нормально. А события можно посмотреть в справке. По-моему, должно подойти "activate". 

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkstatusicon.html#signal-gtkstatusicon--activate

Comment: Я уже нашел хороший справочник, спасибо.